# Historic Premillennial Church in NYC?

Tags: protestantism

How can I find a New York City (preferably Manhattan) church that holds to historic premillennialism (post-trib rapture)?

Comment: Please sharpen question. "Premillennial": Christ returns before the coming millennium. "Post-trib rapture": Believers raptured after the coming tribulation.